# Multiple buttons in Paintcode swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, paintcode

is it possible to have a group of buttons in the same view that does different things when tapping, will frames do the job? or do i have to have different UIVIEWS for each button seperately?

[image: buttons]
thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can check the position of the touch to do thi.

Comment: yes , you need to add button same as view's frame and assign tag for track tapped button .

Comment: You can try to create a collection view. Then, the collection view will be a group of your buttons